# ?SUCHTHAT vs ?IMPLIES in quickcheck

Tags: erlang, quickcheck, triq, proper

In Triq, PropEr, Quickcheck in Erlang what is the difference between using a `?SUCHTHAT` property and the `?IMPLIES`?

From what understand they are both specializations of the values produced by generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are similar:

- [`?SUCHTHAT`](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr/doc/proper_types.html) creates a **generator**, which additionally ensures that each generated value satisfies a constraint.
- [`?IMPLIES`](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr/doc/proper.html) creates a **property**, which has an additional possible result, namely "skip". You can use it after all values have been generated.